# Memory leak in boost or Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, boost, stl

I keep finding leaks in Boost or Visual Studio 2010. A program as simple as this leaks:

```
#include <boost\regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    _CrtMemState state;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&state);

    {
        boost::regex my_filter;
        my_filter.set_expression("filter");
    }

    _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince(&state);
    return 0;
}
```

And return

```
Dumping objects ->
{174} normal block at 0x00195C28, 1024 bytes long.
 Data: <    8\          > 00 00 00 00 38 5C 19 00 00 00 00 00 00 CD CD CD 
{172} normal block at 0x00195B90, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <  <         pO  > B8 D3 3C 01 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 70 4F 19 00 
{171} normal block at 0x00195B48, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < P      > BC 50 19 00 00 00 00 00 
{170} normal block at 0x00195AF8, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <  <         XQ  > E8 D3 3C 01 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 58 51 19 00 
{169} normal block at 0x00195A98, 32 bytes long.
 Data: < R   R   R      > 80 52 19 00 80 52 19 00 80 52 19 00 09 0C 00 00 
{168} normal block at 0x00195A48, 20 bytes long.
 Data: < Q   Q   R   Y  > E8 51 19 00 E8 51 19 00 E0 52 19 00 F8 59 19 00 
{167} normal block at 0x001959F8, 16 bytes long.
 Data: < 2=          R  > 94 32 3D 01 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 E0 52 19 00 
{158} normal block at 0x00195968, 80 bytes long.
 Data: <hY  hY  hY      > 68 59 19 00 68 59 19 00 68 59 19 00 CD CD CD CD 
{157} normal block at 0x00195920, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < W      > 0C 57 19 00 00 00 00 00 
{156} normal block at 0x001958B0, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < X   X   X      > B0 58 19 00 B0 58 19 00 B0 58 19 00 CD CD CD CD 
{155} normal block at 0x00195868, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < V      > F8 56 19 00 00 00 00 00 
{154} normal block at 0x001957F8, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < W   W   W      > F8 57 19 00 F8 57 19 00 F8 57 19 00 CD CD CD CD 
{153} normal block at 0x001957B0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < V      > E4 56 19 00 00 00 00 00 
{150} normal block at 0x00195768, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <`3>     > 60 33 3E 01 00 00 00 00 
{149} normal block at 0x001952E0, 1096 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 09 0C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1A 00 
{148} normal block at 0x00195280, 32 bytes long.
 Data: < Z   Z   Z      > 98 5A 19 00 98 5A 19 00 98 5A 19 00 CD CD CD CD 
{147} normal block at 0x00195238, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < 3>     > 14 33 3E 01 00 00 00 00 
{146} normal block at 0x001951E8, 20 bytes long.
 Data: <HZ  HZ          > 48 5A 19 00 48 5A 19 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
{145} normal block at 0x001951A0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < 3>  Z  > 04 33 3E 01 A8 5A 19 00 
{144} normal block at 0x00195158, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < R   Y  > E0 52 19 00 F8 59 19 00 
{143} normal block at 0x00195110, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <pO      > 70 4F 19 00 00 00 00 00 
{142} normal block at 0x00194F70, 356 bytes long.
 Data: < Q              > 10 51 19 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

I find this using boost 1.47 and 1.50
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with SP1
It seems to be in VS2010. I tried to find a hotfix but without any success

Thanks for any tip!

Comment: So did you find a resolution?

Comment: @ahmd0: No... We just live with it for the moment until we upgrade the library and hope it won't be there in a future release. We are using boost 1.47 at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

In both examples, `_CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince` is being called before the destructors for the boost objects have been run, so nothing has been given the chance to tidy itself up. The memory still allocated is almost certainly not a leak.

The code should be modified to ensure that the destructors are run before checking what memory is still allocated:

```
#include <boost\regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    _CrtMemState state;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&state);

    {
        boost::smatch what;
    }

    _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince(&state);
    return 0;
}
```

Or, better yet, use the `_CrtSetDbgFlag` function instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs(v=vs.100).aspx

Set the `_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF` flag. A leak check will then be performed at program exit, after all the global destructors have been run. This makes it much more likely that any items listed are actually leaks.

Comment: That is true for smatch but there is still a problem with:`#include <boost\regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    _CrtMemState state;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&state);

    {
        boost::regex my_filter;
        my_filter.set_expression("filter");
    }

    _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince(&state);
    return 0;
}

Comment: Have you tried using `_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF`? Something may have been allocated that gets destroyed in an `atexit` handler. Or maybe it's a leak. Hard to say. `_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF` is the better way to check this.

Comment: How do you use `_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF`? like this? `_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);` I tried this and no leak found: `int main()
{
 _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
 double* p = new double;
 return 0;
}
`

Comment: I tried `_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF | _CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF );` and it work well thanks! no leak in boost :)